# On proving the continuity of $\arctan$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I read that continuity of $\arctan$ follows from the equation $\arctan x + \arctan 1/x = \pi / 2$ ($x> 0$) and $\arctan x + \arctan 1/x = -\pi / 2$ ($x<0$).

But I can't work out how this follows.

> Please could someone explain to me **how I can use the equality** to prove
>   continuity of $\arctan$?

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ is a continuous function just because its inverse function is increasing and continuous.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio OP stated they want to prove it is continuous using the equalities in the hypothesis.

Comment: *Only* based on the two equalities?

Comment: @Vim I don't know if that is possible! I'm just trying to understand how these equations imply continuity and I can't seem to work it out on my own.

Comment: It looks improbable, since $x$ and $1/x$ are generically far from each other. The identity compares the values of arctan at far away values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't. Consider the function which is the constant $\frac{\pi}{4}$ on $x > 0$, $0$ at $0$, and $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ on $x < 0$. This function has the desired property (that $f(x) + f(1/x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ on $x > 0$, and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ on $x < 0$) but is not continuous.

Comment: What property are you referring to when you write "has the desired property"?

Comment: That $f(x) + f(1/x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ on $x > 0$, and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ on $x < 0$. I'll edit that in.